# Scrolling two RichTextBoxes with one scrollViewer in WPF

Tags: wpf

I have been asked to help a work colleague who is building an application that will be used to implement version control in an offline environment. We need to be able to vertically scroll the content of two RichTextBoxes at the same time, using a single ScrollViewer, similar to how the comparison tool in Visual Studio works. I have an implementation that does work, but I was wondering if there was a better way of doing. it. My code is below.

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2scrollviewer.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2scrollviewer"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="600" Width="825">
<Grid>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ScrollViewer ScrollChanged="RichTextBox_ScrollChanged" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                  Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


        <RichTextBox Grid.Column="1" x:Name="bx1" >
                <FlowDocument>
                <Paragraph>It's the time of the year when plenty of people are counting down the days until Christmas, but if you are reading this there is a very good chance you are probably counting down the days to a different kind of holiday: the December 16th release of Rogue One: A Star Wars Story. We are all excited to spend that joyous day of nerd celebration with some of the best looking creatures to ever come out of the galaxy far, far away.</Paragraph>
                <Paragraph>It's the time of the year when plenty of people are counting down the days until Christmas, but if you are reading this there is a very good chance you are probably counting down the days to a different kind of holiday: the December 16th release of Rogue One: A Star Wars Story. We are all excited to spend that joyous day of nerd celebration with some of the best looking creatures to ever come out of the galaxy far, far away.</Paragraph>
                <Paragraph>It's the time of the year when plenty of people are counting down the days until Christmas, but if you are reading this there is a very good chance you are probably counting down the days to a different kind of holiday: the December 16th release of Rogue One: A Star Wars Story. We are all excited to spend that joyous day of nerd celebration with some of the best looking creatures to ever come out of the galaxy far, far away.</Paragraph>
                <Paragraph>It's the time of the year when plenty of people are counting down the days until Christmas, but if you are reading this there is a very good chance you are probably counting down the days to a different kind of holiday: the December 16th release of Rogue One: A Star Wars Story. We are all excited to spend that joyous day of nerd celebration with some of the best looking creatures to ever come out of the galaxy far, far away.</Paragraph>
                </FlowDocument>
            </RichTextBox>
        <RichTextBox Grid.Column="2"
                     ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"


                     x:Name="bx2">
        <FlowDocument>
            <Paragraph>It’s the time of the year when plenty of people are counting down the days until Christmas, but if you are reading this there is a very good chance you are probably counting down the days to a different kind of holiday: the December 16th release of Rogue One: A Star Wars Story. We are all excited to spend that joyous day of nerd celebration with some of the best looking creatures to ever come out of the galaxy far, far away.</Paragraph>
            <Paragraph>It’s the time of the year when plenty of people are counting down the days until Christmas, but if you are reading this there is a very good chance you are probably counting down the days to a different kind of holiday: the December 16th release of Rogue One: A Star Wars Story. We are all excited to spend that joyous day of nerd celebration with some of the best looking creatures to ever come out of the galaxy far, far away.</Paragraph>
            <Paragraph>It’s the time of the year when plenty of people are counting down the days until Christmas, but if you are reading this there is a very good chance you are probably counting down the days to a different kind of holiday: the December 16th release of Rogue One: A Star Wars Story. We are all excited to spend that joyous day of nerd celebration with some of the best looking creatures to ever come out of the galaxy far, far away.</Paragraph>

        </FlowDocument>
    </RichTextBox>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Code Behind

```
   public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
          public MainWindow()
      {
        InitializeComponent();
       }

    private void RichTextBox_ScrollChanged(object sender,   ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        ScrollViewer scroll = (ScrollViewer)sender;
        bx1.ScrollToVerticalOffset(scroll.VerticalOffset);
        bx2.ScrollToVerticalOffset(scroll.VerticalOffset);

    }
}
```

Comment: Seems OK. Are you having any problems with this?

Comment: Seems to be working ok, just wanted some more experience input, thanks for your time